# 403 forbidden in httpd on Fedora 27

Tags: httpd, fedora, httpd.conf

My server returns the following error over and over with the permissions set
as below.  This is the virtual host running on Fedora 27.

From `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` at the bottom of the file:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/andrei06041990/sites/cosmeticremix"
    ServerName cosmeticremix.dev
    ServerAlias www.cosmeticremix.dev
    <Directory "/home/andrei06041990/sites/cosmeticremix">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        #AllowOverride All
        AllowOverride None
        Require all Granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

What additional information should I provide to help troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Have you checked `SELinux`? Usually it blocks such configs.

Comment: no how do i do that?

Comment: Show output for command `getenforce`. If it `Enforcing`, then your SELinux is enabled.

Comment: is says Permisive

Comment: Now check for permissions.

Comment: this is what i get

Comment: File: sites
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd02h/64770d Inode: 9437422     Links: 6
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (   48/  apache)   Gid: (   48/  apache)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0
Access: 2017-11-17 12:17:58.427008961 -0500
Modify: 2017-11-17 04:46:10.892421365 -0500
Change: 2017-11-17 11:29:39.723196791 -0500
 Birth: -

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68897/discussion-between-alexander-tolkachev-and-andrei-claudiu).

Comment: but i did a chown -R apache:apache sites

Comment: The first thing to do in all cases like that, before applying any blind counter-measures is to check your logfiles where Apache should have written more details on the reason of the 403 error.

Comment: there are no more

Answer (score 1):

According your error from, [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451922/apache-access-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing) is easy. Just do a chmod +x on your user dir, and restart Apache.

Comment: hei sorry my net was out

Comment: but i still get the default installation page